# Proximity Sensor is mocked to 5cm, screen still goes dark

Tags: xposed-framework, sensors, proximity-sensor

After replacing the display of my Xiaomi Mi A2 Lite, my proximity sensor is giving me wrong values (saying, my phone is always covered).
I mocked my sensors using the [XPosed Sensor Disable App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mrchandler.disableprox), and the various sensor test apps tell me, that the distance is 5cm (the maximum). Still, my phone's screen goes black when playing audios or making a call. Am I missing something? Maybe another sensor's setting?

The way I mocked my Sensors was the following:

LTR579 ALSPS: 5cm, LTR579 ALSPS-Non Wakeup Secondary: 0cm

I'm really out of ideas, it would be great if someone could help me! I'd hate having to open my phone again, and I'll happily do without the screen going black feature. I honestly have no idea why the test says "5cm", but the phone still decides to go dark. >:(

Thanks alot for any ideas!

Comment: The proximity sensor is usually only used to disable the screen immediately in phone calls. Otherwise it is not used. If your screen goes black most likely it is simply the display timeout. But this timeout is not influenced by the proximity sensor.

Comment: @Robert the screen is immediately disabled when playing an audio in telegram/whatsapp or when making a phone call, that's the issue that I'm having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I thought I had tried all possible combinations, but seems like I forgot to save the mocked values. With LTR579 ALSPS: 0cm and LTR579 ALSPS-Non Wakeup Secondary: 5cm, it now works as I want it to. I have no idea why the sensor testing app gave me wrong values.

EDIT: Turns out that the [app i used to calibrate the sensor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobiledirection.proximitysensorreset&hl=de&gl=US) with at the very beginning was the reason for the unwated behaviour after all. Just uninstalling it was not enough, I had to reinstall it, choose the option to reset the calibration, uninstall it, reboot the phone, and THEN override the sensors in the XPosed app.